# How to know if user touched the iAd?

Tags: ios, iad

I move the screen up when textfield is editing to bring up the keyboard, but when I click the iAd while the screen is up  when I close the ad the screen comes down and the keyboard stays so when I hide the keyboard the screen goes down more so everything is half a screen down.how do I fix this? I thought if I could recognize when the iAd was clicked I could keep the screen up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a callback/delegate method available for the application to know the touch of the user in iAD.

Here is what apple says about it,

> If the banner view covered your application’s user interface, it calls
>   the delegate’s bannerViewActionDidFinish: method after the interface
>   is restored.
>
> if your interface was covered by the banner view, your application
>   could still be moved into the background later, either because the
>   advertisement launched another application or because the user chose
>   to do so. In all cases, if your user interface was covered by the
>   banner view, it is uncovered and your delegate’s
>   bannerViewActionDidFinish: is invoked before your application moves to
>   the background. Because the application may be moving into the
>   background, your delegate should return quickly from its
>   bannerViewActionDidFinish: method.